# Instalar paquetes mediante PIP, aunque ya existan en el sistema base

Tags: python, pip

He creado un `venv` para un proyecto, pero estoy teniendo problemas durante la instalación de paquetes mediante `pip`.

- Creé el `venv`:

  `python -m venv .venv`
- Lo activo (estoy en un sistema Linux):

  `source .venv/bin/activate`

  Con lo cual el *prompt* cambia a `(.venv)`, por lo que doy por bien realizada la activación.
- Ahora, intento instalar `PyGObject` siguiendo [su documentación](https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html):

  `pip install PyGObject`

  > Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
  > Requirement already satisfied: PyGObject in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (3.42.1)
  > Requirement already satisfied: pycairo>=1.16.0 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from PyGObject) (1.20.1)

Lo cual es correcto, porque esos paquetes están instalador **en el sistema base**. Pero yo lo que quiero es **instalarlos en el `venv`**.

Rebuscando por internet, encontré un *post* (no tengo la URL) en el que recomendaban borrar la variable de entorno `PYTHONPATH`, consejo que seguí:

```
deactivate
unset PYTHONPATH
source . .venv/bin/activate
pip install PyGObject
```

Sin cambios apreciables. Sigue mostrando la indicación de que el paquete ya se encuentra instalado.

- ¿ Como fuerzo a `pip` (dentro del `venv`) a no tener en cuenta los paquetes en el sistema base ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Buen día,

Ignoro si al crear tu ambiente virtual activaste la bandera para compartir los paquetes instalados en el sistema base `--system-site-packages` o si por alguna razón el ambiente virtual heredó los paquetes instalados en el sistema base.

Lo que puedes hacer es utilizar `pip install --ignore-installed PyGObject` que ignorará lo que ya esté instalado en el sistema base y forzará la instalación del paquete en el ambiente virtual.